# How to delete a folder and its sub folders? rm -R not working

Tags: command-line, mac

I am trying to delete a folder that has sub folders, and a git repository.

Doing:

```
rm -R folder_name/
```

doesn't work, it prompts me for some folders that are GIT specific?

Comment: @user27449: if Ignacio's answer solves your issue, please mark it as the answer, for the reference of those looking to assist.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's working fine, it's just asking you if you're certain you want to delete files and folders you normally wouldn't be able to. Add `-f` if you want to force deletion of anything it comes across.